# An example of how to implement firebase-auth in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: firebase, polymer

I'm a bit lost on how to implement the [firebase-auth](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element?active=firebase-auth) element. Any examples would be appreciated, I haven't managed to find any yet.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to track [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609048/polymer-1-0-i-need-an-example-of-a-login-button) too. *(I upvoted you because we are both in the same situation.)* =]

Comment: I found [this example](https://github.com/HackITtoday/hi9-login/blob/master/hi9-login.html) that actually works for me (if you change the firebase url, and add this as an element). I've not yet got as far as getting data from the server, but the auth process works at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609048/polymer-1-0-i-need-an-example-of-a-login-button), [Glenn Vandeuren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4411161/glenn-vandeuren) posts the following:

---

### Element

```
<!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2015 Glenn Vandeuren. All rights reserved.
-->
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../paper-button/paper-button.html">

<dom-module id="login-button">

  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>

  <template>
    <paper-button raised>Login using <span>[[service]]</span></paper-button>
  </template>

</dom-module>

<script>

  Polymer({

    is: 'login-button',

    properties: {
      service: String
    },

    listeners: {
      'tap': '_handleTap'
    },

    _handleTap: function () {
      this.fire('login', this.service);
    }

  });

</script>
```

### Index

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <title>login-button Demo</title>
    <script src="../../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="../login-button.html">
  </head>
  <body>

    <login-button service="google"></login-button>
    <login-button service="twitter"></login-button>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener('login', function(service) {
        // handleLogin();
        alert(service.detail);
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: any idea on how to achieve this when using provider = custom ?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up getting auth to work by adapting [this](https://github.com/HackITtoday/hi9-login/blob/master/hi9-login.html) example element by HackITtoday for my firebase urls. It's as simple as adding the element like:

```
<hi9-login></hi9-login>
```