# Polymer 1.0: What is replacing <firebase-element>?

Tags: authentication, firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0

I need to build a user authentication (login) element using `<firebase-login>`.

[This page](https://github.com/polymer/firebase-element) says `<firebase-element>` is being deprecated in Polymer 1.0.

What is intended to replace it?

Comment: See the Polymer element catalog [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element) which details the 3 new firebase elements release as part of Polymer 1.0

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! @BenThomas. Weird it's out of order [on this page](https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=google-web-components). But I see why, it starts with "f" not "g." So I totally missed it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An example of how to implement firebase-auth in Polymer 1.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581056/an-example-of-how-to-implement-firebase-auth-in-polymer-1-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `<firebase-auth>.`

- [Github Demo](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/firebase-element/blob/master/demo/x-login.html)
- [Documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element?active=firebase-auth)